# Image in front off text?

Tags: c#, image, xaml, listview, xamarin

So with this code my image is over the text, how do i get the image in front of the text?

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" BackgroundColor="DeepSkyBlue" >
    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
    <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" />
    <Label Text="{Binding Tlfnr}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small"  />
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Is 'over the text' not the same as 'in front of the text'?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/2abedde435bdddf0a1992ac7490565b5 number 2 image, thats what i want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" BackgroundColor="DeepSkyBlue" >
    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" />
        <Label Text="{Binding Tlfnr}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Small"  />
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```